# How would I add numbers between 1 and 20 to a list using a for loop without using range()

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a replacement for the range command that can be used in for loop to add the numbers between 1 and 20 to a list.

Comment: Why don't you want to use range?

Answer (score 2):

Simple for loop

```
i = 1
l = []
while i <= 20:
    l.append(i)
    i = i + 1
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.linspace(1, 20, num=20)`

Answer (score 0):

If we are to avoid using a builtin as crucial as `range`, we might as well have some fun doing so.

```
l = []
while len(l) < 20:
    l.append(len(l) + 1)

print(l)
```

### Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```